# Is it safe to read/write register values without Data Memory Barriers?

Tags: c, c++

I'm trying to utilize the BCM2835's BSC/SPI slave peripheral to use the Pi as an effective I2C slave, however I've been running across some segmentation faults when I try to write to the configuration register to enable the slave.  Examination with `gdb` shows that the issue occurs when [Mike M](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835) is trying to run the following assembly:

```
__asm__("\
mov r10,#0               \n\
mcr p15,0,r10, c7, c10, 5\n\
ldr %[ret], [%[paddr]]   \n\
mcr p15,0,r10, c7, c10, 5\n"
: [ret] "=r" (ret) : [paddr] "r" (paddr) : "r10", "memory" );
```

While it's worked thus far for all of his code, I'm having issues hooking onto that.  Is there any reason why I should still worry about the memory barriers that his code offers?  And additionally, is there any other way I can view and manipulate the register values with memory barriers other than the ones he's got?